# Why the speaker did not use "to" after "want"?

Tags: grammar, meaning

First of all, I don't know the sentence exactly so it may be one of them :

1. It's hardest nails for me to want not do anything about it.
2. It's hard as nails for me to want not do anything about it.

I think it should be "to want not **to** do anything". Why the second " to" is missing? Does this add something to the meaning? Or is it just contraction?

**Edit:**
Here's a link to the audio. Please, listen starting from 1:40

https://www.wnycstudios.org/story/death-sex-money-lets-talk-about-porn-again

Comment: Did you hear this sentence?  I think you might have misheard it.  Can you provide audio?

Comment: Hi @snailboat Thank you so much for your comment. I edited the post to include the audio.

Comment: I'd originally made a different comment, but listened to it a few more times. It starts at 1:57, and what he says is: *It* ***is*** *hard* ***as*** *f—ing nails for me to want not do anything about it.* Originally, I'd thought the *to* was barely pronounced, but now I believe it's missing altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the sentences you have provided are definitely not correct grammatically. If you heard someone say this in conversation, it may well be that this misspoke, or you misheard.

The closest sentence which makes grammatical sense that I can think of is:

> It's ***as*** hard as nails for me to want not ***to*** do anything about it.

As you correctly identified, the extra 'to' to create the infinitive 'to do' is definitely needed.

The phrase 'as hard as nails' is not very natural in this context. 'Hard as nails' usually means something that is physically hard, not difficult. Someone can be 'hard as nails' if they are tough and strong. A desire to do or not do something can be 'hard' but not usually 'hard as nails'.

And finally, if you were writing this from scratch I'd avoid 'to want not to do' ... it's a clumsy sort of phrase and the placing of 'not' is awkward. You'd be better to say:

> It's hard for me not to want to do anything about it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I edited the question and I made sure that the word *as* is not dropped nor the *to*. Am I right? It seems that he isn't a native speaker, right?

Comment: I'd say he is a native American English speaker, but he makes a bit of a mess of saying the sentence.